# WindowLeaked from Dialog

Tags: android, memory-leaks, progressdialog, toast

I'm having a typical WindowLeaked exception

> 03-03 21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631): Activity
>   com.myapp.Player has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45136c38 that
>   was originally added here 03-03 21:03:26.441:
>   ERROR/WindowManager(631): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.myapp.Player has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45136c38 that
>   was originally added here 03-03 21:03:26.441:
>   ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.(ViewRoot.java:247) 03-03 21:03:26.441:
>   ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
>   03-03 21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>   03-03 21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424) 03-03
>   21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241) 03-03 21:03:26.441:
>   ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802) 03-03
>   21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   android.widget.VideoView$4.onError(VideoView.java:387) 03-03
>   21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1264)
>   03-03 21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-03
>   21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 03-03 21:03:26.441:
>   ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 03-03
>   21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-03
>   21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 03-03 21:03:26.441:
>   ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   03-03 21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 03-03
>   21:03:26.441: ERROR/WindowManager(631):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

None of the answers I've read so far seem to solve it. Here is the code:

```
mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        Toast.makeText(Player.this, "Sorry, unable to play this video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (mToken != null) {
            MusicUtils.unbindFromService(mToken);
        }
        finish();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The only guess I was left with was that the toast was holding on to the activity, but everything I'm reading seems to say the toast doesn't matter. I even tried using getBaseContext(), and then tried putting the toast after finish() to see if it would work. I'm all out of ideas so any help would be awesome.

UPDATE: Here is more of the code

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        media_url = extras.getString("media_url");
        setContentView(R.layout.video_player);
        //Start progress dialog so user knows something is going on
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                playVideo();
            }
        });
    }

    private void playVideo() {
        try {
            if (media_url == null || media_url.length() == 0) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(VideoPlayer.this, "File URL/media_url is empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
                if (media_url.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                    mVideoView.start();
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                current = media_url;
                mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(media_url));
                ctlr=new MediaController(VideoPlayer.this);
                ctlr.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
                mVideoView.setMediaController(ctlr);
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        mVideoView.start();
                    }
                });
                mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                        Toast.makeText(VideoPlayer.this, "Sorry, unable to play this video",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        if (mToken != null) {
                            MusicUtils.unbindFromService(mToken);
                        }
                        finish();
                        return false;
                    }
                });


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void startPlayback() {

        if(mService == null)
            return;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String filename = "";
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().length() > 0) {
            String scheme = uri.getScheme();
            if ("file".equals(scheme)) {
                filename = uri.getPath();
            } else {
                filename = uri.toString();
            }
            try {
                mService.stop();
                mService.openFileAsync(filename);
                mService.play();
                setIntent(new Intent());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(tag, "couldn't start playback: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private ServiceConnection osc = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName classname, IBinder obj) {
            mService = IMediaPlaybackService.Stub.asInterface(obj);
            startPlayback();
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName classname) {
            mService = null;
        }
     };
```

Error is occurring when it is a video type the device can't play

Comment: What's that `progressDialog.dismiss()` doing there? I think we would need more code to be able to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @dmon it is just to get rid of the loading progressDialog. Even if I completely remove the progressDialog from the activity, I still get the error so that isn't the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try to show your Toast through [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) ?

Something like:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
       Player.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           void run() {
               Toast.makeText(Player.this, "Sorry, unable to play this video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               progressDialog.dismiss();
               if (mToken != null) {
                    MusicUtils.unbindFromService(mToken);
                }
                finish();
           }
        );
        return false;
    }
```

**EDIT**:

Here is more...below is the code (in Froyo) for the VideoView.

Seems like the error comes from the AlertDialog.Builder... but based on your code, it should not even get there since the error should be handled higher when mOnErrorListener is not null...

Can you check whether your error handler is being called ? Maybe try to not call finish() there ?

```
 private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener mErrorListener =
        new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int framework_err, int impl_err) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + framework_err + "," + impl_err);
            mCurrentState = STATE_ERROR;
            mTargetState = STATE_ERROR;
            if (mMediaController != null) {
                mMediaController.hide();
            }

            /* If an error handler has been supplied, use it and finish. */
            if (mOnErrorListener != null) {
                if (mOnErrorListener.onError(mMediaPlayer, framework_err, impl_err)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            /* Otherwise, pop up an error dialog so the user knows that
             * something bad has happened. Only try and pop up the dialog
             * if we're attached to a window. When we're going away and no
             * longer have a window, don't bother showing the user an error.
             */
            if (getWindowToken() != null) {
                Resources r = mContext.getResources();
                int messageId;

                if (framework_err == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK) {
                    messageId = com.android.internal.R.string.VideoView_error_text_invalid_progressive_playback;
                } else {
                    messageId = com.android.internal.R.string.VideoView_error_text_unknown;
                }

                new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                        .setTitle(com.android.internal.R.string.VideoView_error_title)
                        .setMessage(messageId)
                        .setPositiveButton(com.android.internal.R.string.VideoView_error_button,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        /* If we get here, there is no onError listener, so
                                         * at least inform them that the video is over.
                                         */
                                        if (mOnCompletionListener != null) {
                                            mOnCompletionListener.onCompletion(mMediaPlayer);
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

**MORE EDIT:**

Change the onError handler to `return true;`

Then the "default" error handler will not try to build this AlertDialog

Comment: I tried this, and modified versions of it, but am still getting the error

Comment: Is your Player activity still running when this code gets executed ?

Comment: I thought that might have been the problem so I tried calling `arg0.release()` and `mPlayer.release()` before finishing, but both caused the app to crash

Comment: What line is actually causing the error ? Is it the toast or the progressDialog.dismiss() ?

Comment: It isn't giving a line number for what is causing the error, only what is posted above. I tried completely removing both the toast and progressDialog (removed completely, not just the .dismiss), but still got the WindowLeaked error. I removed every instance of MusicUtils as well, so it seems now like it would be the MediaPlayer, but I can't figure out why

Comment: Yes it does... ERROR/WindowManager(631): at android.widget.VideoView$4.onError(VideoView.java:387), I believe that's in your code... what is at line 387 (or used to be) ?

Comment: [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) is an Android Widget so I don't have the code

Comment: I know the error handler is being called because the toast is showing up and the finish is being called. I tried removing the finish call and it leaves me with three instances of a "Cannot Play Video" error box

Comment: What version of Android are you running this on ? Seems to me the problem is around there...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8803/discussion-between-cameronw-and-matthieu)

Answer (score 0):

The Error listener event is probably not coming back to you on the UI (looper) thread. You need to post an event to a handler (registered on the UI thread) have the handler show the Toast and dismiss the progress dialog.

Comment: Such as creating an onClick listener with all of the code from the error listener, but not registering it to anything. When the error occurs, just call the onClick listener? Sorry, I'm not exactly an expert when it comes to Android...

Answer (score 0):

This error is still relevant, I got this error when changing orientation while the video was still playing. I fixed it using the stopPlayback();

Since my fragment is recreated on orientation change, the onCreateView method restarted the video for me.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;

    videoPlayerView.stopPlayback();

}
```