# how to solve android.view.WindowLeaked: progressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

i got an error using ProgressDialog..below is the logcat :

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.data.CariBuku has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{137ca20 V.E...... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:368)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
    at com.example.data.CariBuku$Cari.onPreExecute(CariBuku.java:126)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
    at com.example.data.CariBuku$1.onClick(CariBuku.java:77)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:9879)
    at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:6248)
    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2664)
    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9234)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2395)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1727)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2725)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:534)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:241)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
```

i have dismiss the dialog in onPostExecute method but still got this error...pls help...thanks  :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WindowLeaked from Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551721/windowleaked-from-dialog)

Comment: do you also dismiss it in onPause?

Answer (score 0):

Window leaked error come when your activity finishing but dialog still displaying.

There are number case by which you can handle this error:

- Remove each dialog when activity destroying.
- Display dialog `if(!HomePage.this.isFinishing())`
- When dismiss dialog also check dialog not null
- I have dismiss the dialog in onPostExecute method but still got this error

--Are you finish activity after dismiss ?